# Partial differentiation of a integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

If I have:
$$f(x,y)=\int_{x}^{y}e^{-t^2}dt$$
To calculate that, I change the t to y and x to get:
$$e^{-y^2}(e^{-y^2})'-e^{-x^2}(e^{-x^2})$$
With the differentials being in respect to x and y for each partial derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $\displaystyle \int_{x}^y = \displaystyle \int_{0}^y - \displaystyle \int_{0}^x \Rightarrow f_x = -e^{-x^2}, f_y = e^{-y^2}$.

Comment: So I place the limit of integration on the variable $t$?

Comment: Yes, and split it in two pieces like above is easier.

Comment: If I had $x^2$, then the result would be multiplied by 2? Like when taking normal derivatives of integrals... I mean on the partial derivative with respect to x...

Comment: It would then be $-2xe^{-x^4}$

Comment: Last time I annoy you. You know any reliable software to calculate expressions like that? I need to train but the list of exercises here don't have the actual answer, I can't see my mistakes...

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is the current king of math software.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be antiderivative of $g(t)=e^{-t^2}$(F'(t)=g(t)), then by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$f(x,y)=\int_{y}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt=F(x)-F(y)$$

So

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$$

The same with second partial derivative.